# Two stages with different viewports, how to remove blackbars between them

Tags: libgdx

I have two stages, one for the background image (using FillViewport to stretch the image)
Another one use Fitviewport to display game objects.
How do I remove the blackbars to display the background of the first stage ?
I tried Extendviewport for second stages but it will show the gap at the right for 1280x720 devices (how could I split the gap to left ?)

```
public LoginScreen(final MyGame gam) {
        game = gam;

        stageBG = new Stage(new FillViewport(800, 480));
        textureBackground = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
        stageBG.addActor(new Image(textureBackground));

        stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(640, 480, 1280, 720));
        table = new Table();

        textureLoginArea = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("login-area.png"));
        textureGirlGreen = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("girl-green.png"));

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        table.setBounds(415, 15, 374, 459);
        table.setBackground(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(textureLoginArea)));

        stage.addActor(table);
    }
@Override
    public void render(float v) {
        stageBG.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stageBG.draw();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stage.getBatch().begin();
        stage.getBatch().draw(textureGirlGreen, 120, 0);
        stage.getBatch().end();

        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stageBG.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid using two stages with different viewports. You will get into more trouble. If you want a background image with an login overlay you should just use scene2d. Or just use two stages with the same viewport and scale your overlay manually.

However you could use frame buffers with blending to overdraw the black bars.